# Javascript: Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, html

I have ran into a problem where it gives me Maximum call stack size exceeded. This is getting really confusing at this point becuase i do have a base case.

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="Input">

        <script language='javascript'>
        var input = document.getElementById("Input").value;
        var n = parseInt(input);

        function fib(n){
            if(n <= 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
            }
        }


    </script>

    <button onclick= "fib(n)">aButton </button>

</body>
```

Comment: Pass the value of the of the input *as an argument*, not inside the function...

Comment: After your edit, your function makes less sense than before. Please post the **real** code that's causing problems. If the update is really accurate, the problem is that the function doesn't have a parameter and reloads the starting value of `n` from the user input on each call.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my coding while asking this question, I will post the most recent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a little flaw, which is causing the function to be called infinitely.

As a base case, instead of testing `n < 2`, try `n<=1`, like this:

```
function fib(n){
   if(n <= 1)
   {
     return 1;
   }
   else
   {
      return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
   }
}
```

Otherwise it continues to call `fib()` without ever triggering the base case!

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Alright! After you edited your code I see another big error you have here...

`var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("Input").value)`

Gets the input value *every time* `fib()` is called. This means you are never allowing the base case to ever be called! Instead `fib()` is called and n is initialized to the original value every time.

Instead, try something like:

```
var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("Input").value);
function fib(n){
       if(n <= 1)
       {
         return 1;
       }
       else
       {
          return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
       }
    }
document.write(fib(n));
```

**EDIT 2**

Try this:

```
<script language='javascript'>
        function runfib() {
             var input = document.getElementById("Input").value;
             var n = parseInt(input);
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fib(n);
        }

        function fib(n){
            if(n <= 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1);
            }
        }   
</script>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="Input">   
    <button onclick= "runfib()">Get My Fib #!</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

</body>
```

It uses a helper function called `runfib()`. You were trying to invoke `fib()` without any parameters, among other errors.

This code is tested and works. (Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7oeexzy/))

Comment: Note the edit. It's all different now.

Comment: Oh jeez... Yeah that changes things

Comment: still the same error message

Comment: The question was edited again, with seemingly correct code...

Comment: Welp, in that case I'm done helping :-). Hope he figures it out.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my code while asking the questions. I will stop editing now.

Comment: Do you see what needed to be changed to fix your code? Essentially you needed to pass `n` into `fib()` *only once*! But it seems you figured that out and edited your question, so now it works.

Comment: Yeah, i edited that afer your response, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer again! Hope it helps

Comment: it worked, thank you! I will be comparing to see what is really going on with my code, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it! If it worked don't forget to accept the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try memoizing your fib:

```
var fib = (function(){
  var memo = [0,1];

  return function fib(n) {
    var result = memo[n];

    if (typeof result === 'number') {
     return result;
    } else {
     memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
     result = memo[n];
    }
    return result;
  }
})();
```

It'll cut down the number of computations exponentially. I ran fib(400) and it worked fine.